# How to call/hook kernel mode APIs from user mode?

Tags: vb6, kernel, usermode

I'd love to dive into kernel hooking - but my problem is that I don't like C/C++. But I've over 10 years experience in VB6 programming and would call my self as an expert in this language. So my question is if it was possible to use a tiny C kernel mode driver - which could be controlled by VB from the user mode via the DeviceIoControl API so that I could to call or hook any kernel mode API?

Comment: What do you want to do with kernel hooking? If you can be specific about your goals, some can suggest alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Years ago I read an excellent book on the topic, Subclassing and Hooking with Visual Basic by Stephen Teilhet, and it really opened my eyes on the possibilities out there (with regard to Visual Basic 6).  I suggest you purchase it and check it out.

Here is a [review](http://www.vbrad.com/pf.asp?p=Reviews/Books/HookSub.htm) of the book - it also includes an interview with the author.

Answer (score 0):

no,you should lean VC++,DDK